# Company Mac OS laptop must connect to Cisco AnyConnect VPN in order to access to the Internet

Tags: macos, network, mojave, vpn

My company Mac OS X laptops (Mojave) are managed devices and in order for the user to connect to Internet, the user must first launch and connect the Cisco AnyConnect VPN otherwise the user is not able to connect to the Internet.

Just for my knowledge, I am looking for the specific file or configuration profile or settings that show me this specific rule.  It must be something on the system that I can see that the Mac system must be connected to Cisco AnyConnect VPN first in order to get Internet access.

I just want to see where this rule is located.

Comment: That is going to depend on the MDM solution your company uses to manage your system. And honestly I am uncomfortable with you asking (for all intents and purposes) how to hack and/or defeat their legitimately installed software.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  We use mandatory proxy for http and https.  So if the laptop is NOT connected to the VPN (meaning cannot hit the proxy server IP address) it cannot route traffic.